# Django-Access dynamically created model

Tags: python, django

I was working on a Django app which requires creating tables dynamically.

```py
def dcreatedb(request):
    dbname = request.GET['dbname']
    attrs = {
        'name': models.CharField(max_length=20),
        '__module__': 'data.models'
    }
    model = type(dbname, (models.Model,), attrs)
    with connection.schema_editor() as schema_editor:
        schema_editor.create_model(model)
    return HttpResponse('done')
```

The above `dcreatedb` view creates a model dynamically. But I need to access the same model in some other view but the model is not in the models.py file in the app and created dynamically by the `dcreatedb` view.

```py
def dinsertdb(request):
    dbname = request.GET['dbname']
    # access the dbname model and do some work
    return HttpResponse('work done')
```

for instance let us suppose a model named `books` is created by the `dcreatedb` view dynamically, and now I want to access the same model in the `dinsertdb` view.(Both the `dcreatedb` model and the `dinsertdb` models are in the same `views.py` file under the same app.)
How can this be done?
Thanks

Comment: This sounds like the wrong approach. Why do you need to create models dynamically?

Comment: Suppose whenever a new seller comes a new table is created for the corresponding seller's daily transections. Because putting all the daily transections of all the sellers in a single table makes it messy and makes queries slower, I think. @DanielRoseman

Comment: No it doesn't, as long as you user indexes correctly.

Comment: Oh. I had forgotten about indexing completely. That's a good suggestion. Thanks for that. Please write that in the answer so that I can approve it.@DanielRoseman